# How to prove the following floor function inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, functions, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For any $M\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $n\ge\lceil\log_2(M) \rceil, n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$
M^2\log_2(M)\le 4\sum_{i=1}^n\left(M-\sum_{k=0}^{2^{i-1}-1}\left\lfloor\frac{M+k}{2^i} \right\rfloor\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2^{i-1}-1}\left\lfloor\frac{M+k}{2^i} \right\rfloor\right) < M^2\left[\log_2(M)+\frac12\right]
$$ 
where the equality holds if and only if $\log_2(M)\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So far, I only proved that when $M\ge2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}$, the upper bound holds. and when $M=2^n$, the lower bound is attained. I would be very interested in the rest of the proof. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the above inequality is equivalent to proving the following one. $$ M^2\log_2(M)\le 4\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil\log_2(M)\rceil}\left(M-2^{i-1}\left\lfloor\frac12+\frac{M}{2^i} \right\rfloor\right)\left(2^{i-1}\left\lfloor\frac12+\frac{M}{2^i} \right\rfloor\right)<M^2\left[\log_2(M)+\frac12\right]$$ as the second terms are exactly the same.

Comment: I have proved the whole inequality by induction. Still, I'm very interested in any other proofs if available.